# Are there any female heroines in Shinto mythology?

Tags: japanese, shinto, heroism

Female heroines are rare in mythology. In Greek, off the top of my hippocampus, I can only recall one, Atlanta. In Chinese folklore, possibly the most popularly known, Hua/Fa Mulan. Does Shinto mythology (Japanese folklore) have a similar heroin legend?

Answer (score 2):

> Amaterasu or Amaterasu-ōmikami is one of the major deities in the animistic Shinto religion of Japan; her full name means “Great Divinity Illuminating Heaven.” One of the world’s few female solar deities, a principal myth featuring Amaterasu depicts her conflict with her brother, Susanoo, god of storms and the sea. Angered with Susanoo because he threw a flayed horse into her weaving hall (rude), Amaterasu withdrew to a cave and brought an age of darkness upon the world. She was eventually coaxed into leaving the cave (pictured above), but Susanoo was banished from heaven. As a gesture of reconciliation, he gifted her the legendary sword Ama-no-Murakumo-no-Tsurugi (天叢雲剣, “Sword of the Gathering Clouds of Heaven”).

Source: ["The 10 Most Badass Goddesses Of World Mythology"](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/03/18/awesome-goddesses-mythology_n_6881434.html), from [Amaterasu (Encyclopedia Britannica)](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Amaterasu)

> The diverse roles of women in Shinto myths make it difficult for scholars to generalize about women's roles at Shinto's origin.[2](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Amaterasu) Amateratsu, the sun goddess, and Himiko, an early shaman queen of Japan, are central figures in the faith. Other goddesses include Benten, a dragon-woman of good luck, and Inari, a rice goddess who takes the form of kitsune, a vixen (female fox) at many Shinto shrines.[3] The Kojiki, a collection of stories which form Shinto practices, purport to be collected from a courtesan, Hieda no Are, and written down at the request of an Empress, Gemmei.[3]

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_in_Shinto